# How do I use a concatenated element id with .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 input boxes (streamInput1-4) and 4 buttons (button1-4) and I'm trying to use a loop to assign each button to its corresponding input box, but for some reason the buttons won't click when I use a concatenated element id with the .click() method.

**This code works:**

```
document.getElementById("streamInput1")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById("button1").click();
    }
});
```

**But this code does not:**

```
var numOfPlayers = 4;
var ii;

for ( ii = 1 ; ii <= numOfPlayers ; ii++ ) {
  document.getElementById("streamInput"+ii)
      .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          document.getElementById("button"+ii).click();
      }
  });
}
```

I found that using "button1" in place of "button"+ii **will** work but "streamInput1" in place of "streamInput"+ii **won't** work. So only the concatenated element id with .click() isn't working properly.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In first code snippet you have added event listener  on  **chatInput** . In second code snippet that does not work has event listener on **streamInput** . Make sure you are adding event listener on proper element.

Comment: I am indeed using the correct elements. Sorry for the confusion, I will edit the post. In the complete document, I use the addEventListener on 5 elements, chatInput, streamInput1 streamInput2, streamInput3, and streamInput4. I would just like to shorten the code by using a loop. Thank you for your reply @KandarpKalavadia

Comment: @JoshPratt I have modified your code below. Basically, when the `keyup` event occurs, `ii` has a different value as the final `for` loop iteration changed its value out of its bounds with `ii++`. Hence `ii` should be persisted somehow or in the same input element to reuse the same at the time of the event occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the modified code:

```js
var numOfPlayers = 4;
var ii;


for ( ii = 1 ; ii <= numOfPlayers ; ii++ ) {
  var elm = document.getElementById("streamInput"+ii);
  elm.index = ii;
  elm.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
     var index = event.target.index;
      event.preventDefault();
      if (event.keyCode == 13) {
          document.getElementById("button"+index).click();
      }
  });
}



function onClick(e) {
  console.log('button clicked:' + e.target.id);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" id="streamInput1" /> <input type="button" value="Update" id="button1" onclick=onClick(event) />
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="streamInput2" /> <input type="button" value="Update" id="button2" onclick=onClick(event) />
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="streamInput3" /> <input type="button" value="Update" id="button3" onclick=onClick(event) />
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <input type="text" id="streamInput4" /> <input type="button" value="Update" id="button4" onclick=onClick(event) />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried the modified code, but any input box that received an enter press would always activate button4. I edited the post to maybe make it more clear what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay, I have updated the code now with a fix. And its now working with 4 set of elements.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: That's great  :-)